# If $f(x)=x^{2}$ and $g(x)=x \sin x+\cos x$; Find out the no of intersecting point

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, problem-solving

**Question from an entrance paper**

If $f(x)=x^{2}$ and $g(x)=x \sin x+\cos x$ then

A. $f$ and $g$ agree at no point

B. $f$ and $g$ agree at exactly one point

C. $f$ and $g$ agree at exactly two point

D. $f$ and $g$ agree at more then two point

---

**My approach**

$f(x)=x^{2}$

$g(x)=x \sin x+\cos x$

$\Rightarrow f(x)=g(x)$

$\Rightarrow x^{2}=x \sin x+\cos x$

$\Rightarrow x^{2}-x \sin x-\cos x=0$

$\Rightarrow F(x)=0$

$F(0)=-1$ & $F(\pi)=\pi^{2}+1 >0 $

$F^{\prime}(x)=2 x-x \cos x$

$F^{\prime}(x)=x(2-\cos x)$

Here $2-\cos x$ is greater than $0$ and $x(2-\cos x)$ will be also greater than 0 for $x>0$
$\Rightarrow F(x)$ is strictly increasing function.

So I can conclude there will be exactly two point on which they will meet.

---

$\boxed{\text{*My question is how to do this without calculus*}}$

*Edit $1$*:- I had thought like this. This a  eq of power $2$,so It must have two roots. These two roots may be real or complex conjugate.Now how to distinguish in **general whether it would have real or imaginary roots for all even powered polynomials**

**ps** Dont give solutions which is similar to mine.

Comment: Try graphing it out.

Comment: graphing a function like this , without desmos and within a time limit of 1-2 minutes it's not so easy

Comment: Well, $f(x) = x^2 $ has only one root - 0. That's where its minima is , too.

Comment: I think that fact may help.

Comment: @SamRubenAbraham give complete solution if u have,other than my approach! TIA

Comment: Sorry if I cause you some trouble. I am a teen of 15, you see.

Comment: @SarGe, so it must have real roots! as power is 2 , can conclude exact two real roots

Comment: Ok, so may I quit ?

Comment: @SarGe how $D^{2} = (1+3 cos^{2}x)$?

Comment: You write "This a eq of power 2,so It must have two roots" That is wrong. This is an equation that contains the term $x^2$. That is not sufficient to conclude that "it must have two roots" Why do you think it is?

Comment: @Amartya Roy, my mistake. $\Delta=\sin^2x+4\cos x$. Also, I see some users do not agree about the quadratic fact, we can write the given equation by completing square$$x=\frac{\sin x\pm\sqrt{\sin^2 x+4\cos x}}{2}$$ and for this to be true you have the argument of root non-negative irrespective of the fact that the given equation is quadratic or not. However, I'm not marking the ease of solving these equation but at least it states that I wasn't wrong.

Comment: @SarGe Of course you can transform F to this equation. But from your equation I cannot see how one can decide how many x satisfy the equation.

Comment: @miracle713, yes, I know that and even accepted this in comment. It was just to clear the dispute that is it a quadratic or not.

Comment: @SarGe it is not a quadratic, but that cannot be shown by expressing x in the way you do.

Comment: @AmartyaRoy Is there a special reason why you want to solve it without calculus? Do you think in the setting where this problem was posed it is required to solve it without calculus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course all statements that use calculus can be proved without using calculus. But this may be very cumbersome. Let's try it here. Here is a picture of the function weare talking about.

[image: the graph of the functions xsin(x)+cos(x),x^2,x^2-xsin(x)-cos(x),x*sin(x),cos(x) in the interval (0,2)]

We can define the functions $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ as projection of the unit vector to the x- and y-axis. The angle t is the lenth of the arc.

[image: uni circle with sin and cos]

The following properties we can immediately conclude from the unique circle diagram:

$$\sin(t)\lt t,\; \forall t$$
$$\cos (t) \; \text{is decreasing in}\; (0,\pi)$$
Also the following formula can be deduced or found in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities)

$$\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos\frac{x+y}2\sin\frac{x-y}2$$

For the function
$$f(x)=x^2$$
and
$$g(x)=x \sin x+\cos x$$
we prove the following

1. In the interval $(0,\infty)$ the function $f$ is increasing
2. In the interval $(0,\pi)$  $f$ is increasing faster than $g$.
3. If $x>\pi$ then $f(x)>g(x)$

$$ f(x+h)>f(x), \forall h>0, x,x+h\in (0,\infty)\tag 1$$
$$ f(x+h)-f(x)>g(x+h)-g(x), \forall h>0, x,x+h\in (0,\pi)\tag 2$$
$$f(x)>g(x), \forall x>\pi \tag 3$$

We have
$$ f(x+h)-f(x)=2xh+h^2>0,\forall x,h>0$$
and so $(1)$ follows.

From
$$ g(x+h)-g(x)\\=(x+h)\sin(x+h)-x\sin x + \cos(x+h)-\cos(x) =  $$
$$(x+h)\sin(x+h)-x\sin x \\
= x(\sin(x+h)-\sin(x))+h \sin(x+h)
= x( 2 \cos(x+\frac h 2)\sin(\frac h 2) ) + h \sin(x+h)\\
<x(2 \frac h 2)+h(x+h)\\
=2xh+h^2\\
=f(x+h)-f(x)
$$

We further have
$$ \cos(x+h)-\cos(x)<0$$
and so we proved $(2)$.

Finally $(3)$ we get from
$$g(x)<x\cdot 1 +1 < 4+1< 3^2 < x^2=f(x), \; \forall  x>\pi$$

We have at least one intersection in $(0,\pi)$ because $f(0)<g(0)$ and $f(1)>g(1)$ and both function are continues. We have only one point of intersection in $(0,\pi)$  because $f$ grows faster than $g$ in $(0,\pi)$ and no further point of intersection in $[\pi,\infty)$ because $f(x)>g(x)$ in $[\pi,\infty)$.

$f$ is even so for symmetry reasons we have exactly two points of intersection.

Answer (score 1):

A solution:

(we want to show that the equation $x^2-x\sin{x} -\cos{x}=0$ has exactly two roots)

Let $g(x)=x^2-x\sin{x} -\cos{x}$
$g$ is continuous (as the sum of the polynomial $x^2$, $-\cos{x}$ and $x\sin{x}$,which is continuous as multiplication of continuous functions).
$g(-\pi)=\pi^2+1>0,g(0)=-1<0, g(\pi)=\pi^2+1>0$
Because g, is continuous applying Bolzano's theorem: g(x)=0 has at least one solution for $x\in(-\pi,0)$ and one for $x\in(0,\pi)$ Therefore g(x)=0 has at least two solutions.

Let's assume g(x)=0 has more than two solutions, then g(x)=0 has at least three solutions $x_1<x_2<x_3$
$g$ is also differentiable, because of Rolle's theorem  $g'(x)=0$ has at least two different solutions. $g'(x)=0\iff x(2+\cos{x})=0\iff x=0$ so it holds $g'(x)=0$ has only one solution, which leads to contradiction. So g(x)=0 has exactly two solutions $\square$

Answer (score 0):

**Solution without calculus**

If $x \ge \frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $g(x) \le \sqrt{x^2 + 1} < x^2$,
and thus $f(x) = g(x)$ has no real solution on $[\frac{\pi}{2}, \infty)$.
Also, $0$ is not a solution of $f(x) = g(x)$.

Since $f(0) < g(0)$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{2}) > g(\frac{\pi}{2})$, by continuity,
$f(x)=g(x)$ has at least one real solution on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.
Let us prove that $f(x)=g(x)$ has exactly one real solution on $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$.
Suppose there exist $0 < s < t < \frac{\pi}{2}$ such that $f(s) = g(s)$ and $f(t) = g(t)$. We have
\begin{align}
\frac{s^2}{\sqrt{s^2+1}} &=  \frac{s\sin s + \cos s}{\sqrt{s^2+1}} = \cos (s - \arctan s), \\
\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} &=  \frac{t\sin t + \cos t}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} = \cos (t - \arctan t).
\end{align}
Since $\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2+1}} - \frac{s^2}{\sqrt{s^2+1}} = 
\sqrt{t^2+1} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2 + 1}} - 
\sqrt{s^2+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2 + 1}} > 0$, we have
$$\cos (s - \arctan s) < \cos (t - \arctan t)$$
which, when combined with
$t - \arctan t \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $s - \arctan s \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$, results in
$$s - \arctan s > t - \arctan t.$$
Thus, we have $\arctan t - \arctan s > t - s$ and $\tan (\arctan t - \arctan s) > \tan (t - s)$
that is $\frac{t - s}{1 + ts} > \tan (t-s)$ which, when combined with $\tan (t-s) > t-s$, results in
$\frac{t - s}{1 + ts} > t-s$ which is impossible. The desired result follows.

Thus, $f(x) = g(x)$ has exactly one real solution on $[0, \infty)$.
Since $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both even, $f(x) = g(x)$ has exactly two real solutions on $(-\infty, \infty)$.
We are done.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this qualifies as "without calculus." You know that $f(x)$ is monotonously decreasing in $\left. \right] \infty,0 \left] \right.$ and monotonously increasing in $\left[ \right. 0,\infty \left[ \right.$ (you know because you can take the derivative, although in this simple case you don't need to; this is why I'm saying I don't know if this qualifies). You also know that $f(x)$ grows faster than $g(x).$ Finally, you also know that $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=1$. Putting all this together yields two solutions.

Comment: That is wrong. One cannot conclude from your observations that f and g intersect only in one point in (0,inf). (x)  grows faster than g(x) if x is big enough, but what is big enough?

Comment: @miracle173 This is an heuristic argument, not a proof. The appears to come from a test to be answered in limited time. Under those circumstances I think I'd use that kind of "solution"